# Plotting Bar Charts on top of Maps in R

Tags: r, chart

I am trying to place bar charts on top of a map of the United States. For whatever reason, I receive this error:

```
> mapbars(x=x1, xllc=-110, yllc=40, barwidth=.5, maxheight=5)
Error in mapbars(x = x1, xllc = -110, yllc = 40, barwidth = 0.5, maxheight = 5) : 
  could not find function "mapbars"
```

Here is the code I've been working with.

````
install.packages("maptools")

library(sp)
library(maptools) # just for easy access to a background map
# load some country borders as a background
data("wrld_simpl")
plot(wrld_simpl)

# zoom on a bit …
usa <- subset(wrld_simpl, NAME=="United States")
plot(usa, axes=TRUE, xlim = c(-125,-70), ylim = c(25, 50))

# data for the bars
x1 <- c(68, 26, 20, 20)

# plot
plot(usa, axes=TRUE, xlim = c(-125,-70), ylim = c(25, 50))

mapbars(x=x1, xllc=-110, yllc=40, barwidth=.5, maxheight=5)
legend(x="topright", pch=22, col="black", pt.bg=rainbow(x1), legend=c("foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar"))

# add another one:
x2 <- c(9, 21, 64, 45, 33, 43, 12, 7)
mapbars(x=x2, xllc=-100, yllc=25, barwidth=.2, maxheight=2)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I realized I accidentally forgot to include the function. It is a custom function. Here it is for anyone else who needs it.

```
# the function 
mapbars <- function (x, xllc = 0, yllc = 0, barwidth=1, maxheight=10){
  # calculate how long each bar needs to be
  bars <- (x/max(x)) * maxheight
  # get some quick colors
  col <- rainbow(length(x))

  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    # figure out x- and y coordinates for the corners
    leftx   <- xllc + ((i-1) * barwidth)
    rightx  <- leftx + barwidth
    bottomy <- yllc
    topy    <- yllc + bars[i]
    # draw the bar
    polygon(x=c(leftx, rightx, rightx, leftx, leftx),
            y=c(bottomy, bottomy, topy, topy, bottomy),
            col=col[i])
  }
}
```